# Need help getting a javascript/html slider to work

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I am trying to get the below html code to work and can't figure it out.  I do not think the domready event is being fired and can't figure out why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style>
.slider {
    background: #CCC;
    height: 16px;
    width: 200px;
}

    .slider .knob {
        background: #000;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
    }

​</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

window.addEvent('domready', function(){

    var slider = $('slider');

    new Slider(slider, slider.getElement('.knob'), {
        range: [0, 100],
        initialStep: 100, steps: 11, wheel: true,
        onChange: function(value){
alert(value);
        }
    });
});

    </script>
  </head>
<body>

<div id="slider" class="slider">
    <div class="knob"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I just want to have a slider on my webpage and can't use html 5 because of browser restrictions.  What is the simplest slider I can use to do this?

Comment: where jquery's script file? i'm pretty sure addevent is not a dom standard, html5 has nothing to do with anything in your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem that I see is in the `var slider = $('slider');` statement.

You need to change it to `var slider = $('#slider');` or `var slider = $('.slider');` depends on if you want to access it via ID or CLASS name.

You can also use http://nivo.dev7studios.com/ as a slider which is a good jQuery plugin that I've been using.

Comment: OK, part of the problem is I needed to add some script files: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js"></script>`

Comment: I am trying to use mootools but am getting annoyed.  I didn't realize I needed all of those script files to get a slider.  What is the simplest slider I can use that works in IE8?  I like the HTML5 slider which works in Chrome and Firefox, but unfortunately I need to get it to work in IE 8 also.

Comment: The slider that I gave you is pretty simple and the only other thing you need for it is to include the jQuery script.

Comment: The website seems to be down, but I see jQuery has a slider that looks simple enough.  It is available here: (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider).  Can you tell me what I need to do to change the colors and other basic formatting?

Comment: I finally got it to work!  More painful that it should have been but I am happy with the results.  Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `window.addEvent();`, why not use

```
$(function(){
    // your code here.
});
```

That uses jQuery's on ready event, so you can be sure it will fire on document ready

And as stated by Odinn above, you are using $('slider'), which means that jquery is looking for an element that is . you need to specifiy if you are searching for an ID `$('#slider')` or by class `$('.slider');`

Other than that, i would keep your console open to look for any errors and post those. Hope that helps.